# What does "sujetador de corbata" mean?

Tags: traducción

I've been reading Spanish Dilbert comics [here](http://www.gocomics.com/espanol/dilbert-en-espanol)

The sentences I don't understand, I've been typing and entering into translate.com.

For the phrase: "*¿Has visto el sujetador de corbata que me dieron por 20 años de servicio?*", it translated: "*Have you seen the bra tie I got for 20 years of service?*"

Is there really such a thing as a "bra tie"? Or does "sujetador de corbata" mean a "clip-on tie" or what?

Comment: I voted closed because automatic translators generate lot of nonsense. You would have a question to clarify mistakes generated by the unability of computers to correctly translate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a *clip-on tie*, but a [*tie clip*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_clip). Google images gives you a good clue in this case.

*bra tie* is a clear case of bad automatic word by word translation.

Comment: _Alfiler de corbata_ would IMHO definitely be the correct translation, as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: @deStrangis the question was not about translating *tie clip* to Spanish, but to translate *sujetador de corbata* to English. Anyway, I don't think there is a "correct" term in Spanish, as there are regional variations. In Argentina it would be called *sujeta corbatas*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if `sujetador de corbata` is the right term, but it might be since in each country it might be called different. I think it refers to a tie clip. In Spain it is usually called `pasador de corbata` o `clip de corbata`. Also `alfiler de corbata` might be used, although I am not sure if it might be a slightly different complement to hold the tie in place clipping it to the shirt.